# JRadioButton Input not responding

Tags: java, swing, input, jradiobutton

i'm new to Java, and programming in general.I am trying an exercise where i create radio buttons which change the background colour when selected.At the moment i am using Eclipse IDE.

Eclipse is not giving me any errors and i can run the b/m program just fine, with the radiobuttons showing up and being clickable.However, the radio buttons fail to change the background colour when i select them. I would appreciate any answers and pointers i can get.

Thanks!

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;


    public class Gui{
    //Declares Variables
    JRadioButton red=new JRadioButton("red");
    JRadioButton blue=new JRadioButton("blue");
    JRadioButton yellow=new JRadioButton("yellow");
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    //Constructor
    public Gui(){
        //Sets title
        super("RadioButton Exercise");
        //Sets layout as default
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //Adds the JRadioButtons
        add(red);
        add(blue);
        add(yellow);
        //Groups the variables
        group.add(red);
        group.add(blue);
        group.add(yellow);
        //Creates HandlerClass object
        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        //When buttons are clicked, HandlerClass is called
        red.addItemListener(handler);
        blue.addItemListener(handler);
        yellow.addItemListener(handler);


    }

    public class HandlerClass implements ItemListener{
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent x){
            if(x.getSource()==red){
                setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            else if(x.getSource()==blue){
                setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            }
            else{
                setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }
        }
    }



    }
```

Comment: Should be addActionListener()

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), with your `main class`, otherwise talking about `JComponents` are added to the `JFrame` directly, then to use `getContentPane.setBackground(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you meant

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {
```

It's not that the `JRadioButton` that is not responding, the problem is that `setBackGround` is being called on the frame directly, rather than it's visible component, i.e. the `ContentPane`. You can use:

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
```

Comment: but I'm miss there extend JFrame, maybe about how is possible to coding another woodoo in Java

Comment: paste error, can be the only logical explanation, given the `super("...")` call

Comment: `Eclipse is not giving me any errors and i can run the b/m program just fine, with the radiobuttons showing up and being clickable.However, the radio buttons fail to change the background colour when i select them.` talking about you are right, but nobody knows, we aren't expert to Star Wars ....

Comment: Doesn't compile without adding this

Comment: yes you miss there implements ItemListener extends JFrame, then could be works, OP is l***

Comment: Reimeus was right, it started working with getContentPane.setBackground(Color.RED);

Thanks a bunch for the help guys! @mKorbel, ill keep the SSCCE in mind next time;)

Answer (score 0):

You have conditions like `x.getSource()==red`. It does not compare `objects`; it compares `object references`.  So even if two different object references point to the *same* object such expression will yield `False`.

If you want to compare objects you need to use `equals` method. For `equal` to produce meaningful result the two objects should be of the same type.

I suggest the following: `(JradioButton)x.getSource().equals(red);`